# Testing hooks callback

Tags: testing, unit-tests

I'm developing a plugin using TDD and one thing that i completely fail to test are... hooks.

I mean OK, i can test hook callback, but how could I test if a hook actually trigger (both custom hooks and WordPress default hooks)? I assume that some mocking will help, but I simply can't figure out what I'm missing.

I installed the test suite with WP-CLI. According to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160567/how-to-properly-test-a-method-that-is-called-by-an-action-hook), `init` hook should trigger, yet... it doesn't; also, the code works inside WordPress.

From my understanding, the bootstrap is loaded last, so it kind of make sense to not trigger init, so the question that remain is: how the heck i should test if hooks are triggered?

Thanks!

The bootstrap file looks like this:

```
$_tests_dir = getenv('WP_TESTS_DIR');
if ( !$_tests_dir ) $_tests_dir = '/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib';

require_once $_tests_dir . '/includes/functions.php';

function _manually_load_plugin() {
  require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../includes/RegisterCustomPostType.php';
}
tests_add_filter( 'muplugins_loaded', '_manually_load_plugin' );

require $_tests_dir . '/includes/bootstrap.php';
```

tested file looks like this:

```
class RegisterCustomPostType {
  function __construct()
  {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_type' ) );
  }

  public function register_post_type()
  {
    register_post_type( 'foo' );
  }
}
```

And the test itself:

```
class CustomPostTypes extends WP_UnitTestCase {
  function test_custom_post_type_creation()
  {
    $this->assertTrue( post_type_exists( 'foo' ) );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're running `phpunit`, can you see failed or passed tests? Did you install `bin/install-wp-tests.sh`?

Comment: I think that part of the problem is that maybe `RegisterCustomPostType::__construct()` is never  called when the plugin is loaded for the tests. It's also possible you are being affected by [bug #29827](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29827#comment:7); maybe try updating your version of WP's unit test suite.

Comment: @Sven: yes, tests are failing; i installed `bin/install-wp-tests.sh` (since i used wp-cli)

@J.D.: RegisterCustomPostType::__construct _is_ called (just added a `die()` statement and phpunit stops there)

Comment: I am not too sure on unit testing side (not my forte), but from literal point of view you can use [`did_action()`](http://queryposts.com/function/did_action/) to check if actions had fired.

Comment: @Rarst: thanks for the suggestion, but it still doesn't work. For some reason, i think that the timing is wrong (tests are ran before `init` hook).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

## Test in isolation

When developing a plugin, the best way to test it is **without** loading the WordPress environment.

If you write code that can be easily tested without WordPress, your code becomes **better**.

Every component that is unit tested, should be tested in **isolation**: when you test a class, you only have to test that specific class, assuming all other code is working perfectly.

[image: The Isolator]

This is the reason why unit tests are called "unit".

As an additional benefit, without loading core, your test will run much faster.

## Avoid hooks in constructor

A tip I can give you is to avoid putting hooks in constructors. That's one of the things that will make your code testable in isolation.

Let's see test code in OP:

```
class CustomPostTypes extends WP_UnitTestCase {
  function test_custom_post_type_creation() {
    $this->assertTrue( post_type_exists( 'foo' ) );
  }
}
```

And let's assume this test **fails**. Who is the **culprit**?

- the hook was not added at all or not properly?
- the method that register the post type was not called at all or with wrong arguments?
- there is a bug in WordPress?

## How it can be improved?

Let's assume your class code is:

```
class RegisterCustomPostType {

  function init() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_type' ) );
  }

  public function register_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'foo' );
  }
}
```

*(Note: I will refer to this version of the class for the rest of the answer)*

The way I wrote this class allows you to create instances of the class without calling `add_action`.

In the class above there are 2 things to be tested:

- the method `init` *actually* calls `add_action` passing to it proper arguments
- the method `register_post_type` *actually* calls `register_post_type` function

I didn't say that you have to check if post type exists: if you add the proper action and if you call `register_post_type`, the custom post type **must** exist: if it doesn't exists it's a WordPress problem.

Remember: when you test your plugin you have to test **your** code, not WordPress code. In your tests you have to assume that WordPress (just like any other external library you use) works well. That's the meaning of **unit** test.

## But... in practice?

If WordPress is not loaded, if you try to call class methods above, you get a fatal error, so you need to mock the functions.

## The "manual" method

Sure you can write your mocking library or "manually" mock every method. It's possible. I'll tell you how to do that, but then I'll show you an easier method.

If WordPress is not loaded while tests are running, it means you can redefine its functions, e.g. `add_action` or `register_post_type`.

Let's assume you have a file, loaded from your bootstrap file, where you have:

```
function add_action() {
  global $counter;
  if ( ! isset($counter['add_action']) ) {
    $counter['add_action'] = array();
  }
  $counter['add_action'][] = func_get_args();
}

function register_post_type() {
  global $counter;
  if ( ! isset($counter['register_post_type']) ) {
    $counter['register_post_type'] = array();
  }
  $counter['register_post_type'][] = func_get_args();
}
```

I re-wrote the functions to simply add an element to a global array every time they are called.

Now you should create (if you don't have one already) your own base test case class extending `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`: that allows you to easily configure your tests.

It can be something like:

```
class Custom_TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        $GLOBALS['counter'] = array();
    }

}
```

In this way, before every test, the global counter is reset.

And now your test code (I refer to the *rewritten* class I posted above):

```
class CustomPostTypes extends Custom_TestCase {

  function test_init() {
     global $counter;
     $r = new RegisterCustomPostType;
     $r->init();
     $this->assertSame(
       $counter['add_action'][0],
       array( 'init', array( $r, 'register_post_type' ) )
     );
  }

  function test_register_post_type() {
     global $counter;
     $r = new RegisterCustomPostType;
     $r->register_post_type();
     $this->assertSame( $counter['register_post_type'][0], array( 'foo' ) );
  }

}
```

You should note:

- I was able to call the two methods separately and WordPress is not loaded at all. This way if one test fails, I know **exactly** who the culprit is.
- As I said, here I test that the classes call WP functions with expected arguments. There is no need to test if CPT really exists. If you are testing the existence of CPT, then you are testing WordPress behavior, not your plugin behavior...

## Nice.. but it's a PITA!

Yes, if you have to manually mock all the WordPress functions, it's really a pain.
Some general advice I can give is to use as few WP functions as possible: you don't have to *rewrite* WordPress, but *abstract* WP functions you use in custom classes, so that they can be mocked and easily tested.

E.g. regarding example above, you can write a class that registers post types, calling `register_post_type` on 'init' with given arguments.
With this abstraction you still need to test that class, but in other places of your code that register post types you can make use of that class, mocking it in tests (so assuming it works).

The awesome thing is, if you write a class that abstracts CPT registration, you can create a separate repository for it, and thanks to modern tools like [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) embed it in all the projects where you need it: **test once, use everywhere**. And if you ever find a bug in it, you can fix it in one place and with a simple `composer update` all the projects where it is used are fixed too.

For the second time: to write code that is testable in isolation means to write better code.

## But sooner or later I need to use WP functions somewhere...

Of course. You never should act *in parallel* to core, it makes no sense. You can write classes that wraps WP functions, but those classes need to be tested too. The "manual" method described above may be used for very simple tasks, but when a class contains a lot of WP functions it can be a pain.

Luckily, over there there are good people that write good things. **[10up](http://10up.com/)**, one of the biggest WP agencies, maintains a very great library for people that want to test plugins the right way. It is [`WP_Mock`](https://github.com/10up/wp_mock).

It allows you to **mock WP functions an hooks**. Assuming you have loaded in your tests (see repo readme) the same test I wrote above becomes:

```
class CustomPostTypes extends Custom_TestCase {

  function test_init() {
     $r = new RegisterCustomPostType;
     // tests that the action was added with given arguments
     \WP_Mock::expectActionAdded( 'init', array( $r, 'register_post_type' ) );
     $r->init();
  }

  function test_register_post_type() {
     // tests that the function was called with given arguments and run once
     \WP_Mock::wpFunction( 'register_post_type', array(
        'times' => 1,
        'args' => array( 'foo' ),
     ) );
     $r = new RegisterCustomPostType;
     $r->register_post_type();
  }

}
```

Simple, isn't it? This answer is not a tutorial for `WP_Mock`, so read the repo readme for more info, but the example above should be pretty clear, I think.

Moreover, you don't need to write any mocked  `add_action` or `register_post_type` by yourself, or maintain any global variables.

## And WP classes?

WP has some classes too, and if WordPress is not loaded when you run tests, you need to mock them.

That's much easier than mocking functions, PHPUnit has an embedded system to mock objects, but here I want to suggest [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) to you. It's a very powerful library and very easy to use. Moreover, it's a dependency of `WP_Mock`, so if you have it you have Mockery too.

## But what about `WP_UnitTestCase`?

The WordPress test suite was created to test WordPress **core**, and if you want to contribute to core it is pivotal, but using it for plugins only makes you test not in isolation.

Put your eyes over WP world: there are a lot of modern PHP frameworks and CMS out there and none of them suggests testing plugin/modules/extensions (or whatever they are called) using framework code.

If you miss factories, a useful feature of the suite, you have to know that there are [awesome things](https://github.com/thephpleague/factory-muffin) over there.

## Gotchas and downsides

There is a case when the workflow I suggested here lacks: **custom database testing**.

In fact, if you use standard WordPress tables and functions to write there (at the lowest level `$wpdb` methods) you never need to *actually* write data or test if data is *actually* in database, just be sure that proper methods are called with proper arguments.

However, you can write plugins with custom tables and functions that build queries to write there, and test if those queries work it's your responsibility.

In those cases WordPress test suite can helps you a lot, and loading WordPress may be needed in some cases to run functions like `dbDelta`.

(There is no need to say to use a different db for tests, isn't it?)

Luckily PHPUnit allows you to organize your tests in "suites" that can be run separately, so you can write a suite for custom database tests where you load WordPress environment (or part of it) leaving all the rest of your tests *WordPress-free*.

Only be sure to write classes that abstract as many database operations as possible, in a way that all the other plugin classes make use of them, so that using mocks you can properly test the majority of classes without dealing with database.

For third time, writing code easily testable in isolation means writing better code.

Comment: Holy crap, a lot of useful info! Thank you! Somehow I managed to miss the whole point of unit testing (until now, I was practicing PHP testing only inside of Code Dojo). I also found about wp_mock earlier today, but for some reason I manage to ignore it.

What pissed me off is that any test, no matter how small it was, it used to take at least two seconds to run (load WP env first, execute the test second).

Thank you again for opening my eyes!

Comment: Thanks @IonutStaicu I forgot to mentions that not loading WordPress makes your tests **a lot** faster

Comment: Indeed. Because on Dojo I had running time of less than 1-200ms (few tests, 20-30 max); wp test suite? enough to pull me out of flow.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the the WP Core unit test framework is an amazing tool for running INTEGRATION tests, which would be automated tests to ensure that it integrates well with WP itself (e.g. there are no accidental function name collisions, etc.).

Comment: @JohnPBloch +1 for good point. Even if using a namespace is enough to avoid any function names collision in WordPress, where everything is global :) But, sure, integrations / functional tests are a thing. I'm playing with Behat + Mink at the moment but I'm still practicing with that.

Comment: Thanks for the "helicopter ride" over the UnitTest forest of WordPress - I'm still laughing at that epic picture ;-)

Comment: @gmazzap This answer seems to cover a lot of the issues which were giving me a lot of headaches. However, either I'm missing one point, or it doesn't cover the case where I need to test a class which creates an instance of another class (e.g. WP_Post): I thought factory-muffin could cover this, but this works when the instance of the class is passed as a dependency. In this case, the instance of the class is created inside the class I'm testing.

Comment: @andrea-sciamanna the problem is that good "testable" code should be written avoiding creating instances of objects inside other objects (unless they are PHP object like `ArrayObject` or value objects), for that very reason. If that happen, and you can't / won't change the code, the only way to "unit" test those objects is to create "stubs". E.g. you can write a custom `WP_Post` class, that is loaded only in tests. That's not easy to maintain, and that's why coding with tests in mind, or even write tests _before_ the code (TDD) is a good thing :)

Comment: I think this may deserve a separate question, especially because there is no room enough to keeps writing here :) Question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233132/unit-tests-dealing-with-dependencies

Comment: What a fantastic answer!