# Why do you need to wrap a function inside array($this, function)

Tags: php

I'm a newbie at PHP and WordPress, so please be gentle!

I'm building a plugin - following a few tutorials, getting it all working.

My question is why is the function I want to call wrapped up in the `array($this, function)`? For example I have this constructor code inside my class

```
 function __construct() {
      add_action( 'admin_init',array( $this, 'getStuffDone' ) );
 }
```

The getStuffDone function gets fired OK - but why does it have to be in the format it is in?

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know enough about OOP to give an informative answer but some research gives a few good references: [Using `add_action` with Class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_with_a_Class) and [PHP Passing to Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable.passing)

Comment: Never register callbacks in constructors. That makes your code untestable.

Comment: @toscho link to an example correct initialization setup? Call a dedicated init() function or something from the constructor?

Comment: @lkraav See gmazzap's [answer to that question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/164138/73).

Answer (score 6):

It's a [PHP callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). You need the syntax to keep a reference to the class instance.

Put it this way -  if you didn't have `$this`, how does the caller know that `getStuffDone` is a method of your class, and not just a regular PHP function? It doesn't.

Using `array( $this, 'getStuffDone' )` says to PHP:

> Hey bro, you need to call the method `getStuffDone` on this instance of my class

Comment: What I don't understand, which may be how I'm reading it, but the first sentence under **[Passing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable.passing)** says `except language constructs such as: array()`, but here we are passing an array. Is this a typo or am I reading the sentence wrong?

Comment: No it's right, but it's referring to functions, not methods. Read the para directly below it.

Answer (score 5):

the *add_action()* function definition looks like:

```
 function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
     return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
 }
```

so according to that it looks like it expects (string,string,int,int)

In a traditional php file the second parameter would simply be one of your function names.

so you would have `add_action('admin_init','my_init_function')`

It looks like you're using a class to encapsulate your plugin. Other classes could have functions in them with the same name (*getStuffDone*).

So your function is only known with reference to your class, that's why you have to specify your class `$this` as well as the function name.

If you're trying to reference a function inside a class you have to use 
[array callable syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable.passing)

See also [codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation, under the "[User Contributed Notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)":

> "To use `add_action()` **when your plugin or theme is built using
>   classes**, you need to use the array callable syntax. You would pass
>   the function to `add_action()` as an array, with `$this` as the first
>   element, then the name of the class method ..."

Answer (score 1):

For future readers this example demonstrates the reason for the syntax. Although possibly a bad practice since the class method is called inside the `add_test` function without initializing the referenced class.

```
function add_test( $reference ){
  $object_instance = $reference[0];
  $object_method = $reference[1];
  $to_return = $object_instance->$object_method();
  return $to_return;
}
class test{
  public function add(){
    $a = $this->get_first();
    $b = add_test(array($this,'get_second'));
    return $a+$b;
   }
   
  public function get_first(){
    return 1;
  }
  
  public function get_second(){
    return 2;
  }
}
$test_instance = new test();
echo $test_instance->add();
```

We're simply storing the reference of the object where the method resides so the function `add_action` can successfully execute the method in question.